# DateTime assigning/returning

Tags: datetime

```
public DateTime EnterDeparture()
{
    DateTime EnterDeparture = new DateTime();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Year:");
    EnterDeparture.AddYears(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
    return EnterDeparture;
}

Train train = new Train(number, EnterDeparture()); //Train takes DateTime (2nd parameter)
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(train.Departure));
```

Rusult in console always the same.
What is wrong?
How to declare DateTime in class Train right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateTime.AddYears()` returns a new DateTime rather than modify the one you call the method on.

You need to return that new DateTime, not the old one:

```
public DateTime EnterDeparture()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Year:");
    return new DateTime().AddYears(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
}
```

Comment: @jjjojjjooo - All you have to do is look at the example.

Comment: One more question. What if I need to call several methods? AddYears and AddMinutes for example ?

Comment: @jjjojjjooo - You would just chain the calls together: `return new DateTime().AddYears(1).AddDays(2).AddMinutes(3);`