# How to work with several fields in DateTime?

Tags: datetime

```
       public DateTime EnterDeparture()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Year:");
            return new DateTime().AddYears(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
        }
    // This will return new DateTime(Without assigned Year)  Cause DateTime is value type.
           public DateTime EnterDeparture()
                {
                    DateTime EnterDeparture = new DateTime();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Year:");
                    EnterDeparture.AddYears(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                    return EnterDeparture;
                }
```

How to work with several fields in DateTime ? (Year,Days for example) Default constructors aren't suitable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DateTime assigning/returning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220422/datetime-assigning-returning)

Comment: Yes, I created that topic but now I am asking another question.

Comment: You're not really asking anything here. Fully describe your problem and provide a meaningful question title.

Comment: How to assign DateTime.AddYears and DateTime.AddHours to same object and return that object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DateTime.AddXXX` methods return new `DateTime` instances, the existing struct does not change. Since each method returns a new instance, you can chain the method calls together. At the very least, you want to capture each return value into a variable. For example:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Today;
DateTime tomorrowAtNoon = myDate.AddDays(1).AddHours(12);
```

You could have also written it like

```
DateTime tomorrow = myDate.AddDays(1);
DateTime tomorrowAtNoon = tomorrow.AddHours(12);
```

Follow?